# javascript recursion with 1++ parameters

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is Dominoes game part and i set three parameters in recursive function and made iterate them to assign the player chips. I want to know what's wrong with it, only shows the chips of the first two players T.T

This is the code:

```js
function messUp() {
fichas=[];
for (i=0;i<7;i++) {
    for (e=0;e<=i;e++) {
        fichas.push('['+i+','+e+']');
    }
} 
fichas.sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5});
document.write(fichas+'<br/><br/>');
}
messUp();

function players(name,hand) {
this.name=name;
this.hand=hand;
}

var main=prompt("Ingrese su nombre","");

function reAsign(h,f,l) {
if (h<4) {
    toHand=[];
    for (f;f<l;f++) {
        toHand.push(fichas[f]);
        delete fichas[f];
    }
    switch (h) {
        case 0: { 
            player1=new players(main,toHand);
            l=14;
        }   
        break;
        case 1: {
            player2=new players("Player 2",toHand);
            l=21;
        }   
        break;
        case 2: {
            player3=new players("Player 3",toHand);
            l=28;
        }
        break;
        case 3: {
            player4=new players("Player 4",toHand);
        }
        break;
    }
    reAsign(h+1,f+7,l+7);
}
}
reAsign(0,0,7);

document.write(player1.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player1.hand+'<br/>');
document.write(player2.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player2.hand+'<br/>');
document.write(player3.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player3.hand+'<br/>');
document.write(player4.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player4.hand+'<br/>');
```

Comment: If you want to test the code that's a work able part

Comment: Why is the `delete fichas[f];` line necessary?

Comment: Well, exactly now... Not necessary. Let me check how it works. Thanks

Comment: Please check how it works before asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: Same problem, but thanks. Code cleaner

Comment: It had nothing to do with the problem anyway @Bernard

Comment: Seems like you've gotten your answer.

Comment: I have it commented out in my code though because it was useless

Comment: Why looks like i got my answer? @Albzi, i have the same problem. What i didn't delete is `delete fichas[f];` and test how it works with out it :/

Comment: Look at my answer below, there's your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because this line

```
reAsign(h+1,f+7,l+7);
```

`f` is already `+7`'d because you iterated it. When you `+7` at the end it goes from `7` to `14` so it's skipping - so `2` was actually `3`'s numbers and then there wasn't any left for `4`.

The same with the `l`.

It should be:

```
reAsign(h+1,f,l);
```

```js
function messUp() {
fichas=[];
for (i=0;i<7;i++) {
    for (e=0;e<=i;e++) {
        fichas.push('['+i+','+e+']');
    }
} 
fichas.sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5});
document.write(fichas+'<br/><br/>');
}
messUp();

function players(name,hand) {
this.name=name;
this.hand=hand;
}

var main=prompt("Ingrese su nombre","");

function reAsign(h,f,l) {
if (h<4) {
    toHand=[];
    for (f;f<l;f++) {
        toHand.push(fichas[f]);
        //delete fichas[f];
    }
    switch (h) {
        case 0: { 
            player1=new players(main,toHand);
            l=14;
        }   
        break;
        case 1: {
            player2=new players("Player 2",toHand);
            l=21;
        }   
        break;
        case 2: {
            player3=new players("Player 3",toHand);
            l=28;
        }
        break;
        case 3: {
            player4=new players("Player 4",toHand);
        }
        break;
    }
    reAsign(h+1,f,l);
}
}
reAsign(0,0,7);

document.write(player1.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player1.hand+'<br/>');
document.write(player2.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player2.hand+'<br/>');
document.write(player3.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player3.hand+'<br/>');
document.write(player4.name+'<br/>');
document.write(player4.hand+'<br/>');
```

Comment: Wow, hours i was thinking about the problem T.T  ... Thanks

Comment: No worries @gAbad - if it solved your problem please click the tick to the left side of the answer :)